# What is the basic type that underlies all other Swift types?

Tags: swift, types, compiler-construction, standard-library, type-systems

I'm currently trying to get a better understanding of Apple's open-source Swift compiler on GitHub. After using Swift for several years, I've gotten used to the philosophy of defining important types like `Int` and `Character` in the standard library as `struct`s, like any other type (opposed to Java and C, that handle `int` and `char` as primitive types in their own way). However, if `Int` is a `struct`, I would assume it is built on some other, lower-level type that is stored as a field (variable) in the `Int` struct. And if this type is itself a `struct`, what type is *it* built on?

Essentially, the question boils down to the following: *What is the "root" type in Swift?* In other words: If we view the set of Swift types in a program as an inductively defined set (user-defined types may use `Int` and `Character`, which are themselves built on other types), what defines the "base case"? I would assume that at least one primitive type that underlies all other is handled as a special case by the compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The primitive-looking types you see defined in the Standard Library are all wrappers of built-in types that aren't publicly exposed. These are prefixed with `Builtin.`, and as far as I understand, aren't Swift types at all. The compiler recognizes access to these constants, and give them special treatment.

I couldn't find any documentation that lists them all out, but I did find the [`swift::getBuiltinType` function](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/1470023addfb86d6cc39e618b7ac48b7dc2b8f6d/lib/AST/Builtins.cpp#L59-L139), which can look them all up. These types include the usual suspects like ints, floats and pointers, but also more curious cases like `RawUnsafeContinuation`, `Job`, and such.

At the time of writing, this is the current list at the time of writing. I added some notes for the ones I know about:

- `VecNxT`: A vector of `N` contiguous `T`s, where `0 < N ≤ 1024`
- `RawPointer`
- `RawUnsafeContinuation`: underpins [`UnsafeContinuation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsafecontinuation)
- `Job`: underpins [`ExecutorJob`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/executorjob)
- `DefaultActorStorage`
- `NonDefaultDistributedActorStorage`
- `Executor`
- `NativeObject`
- `BridgeObject`
- `SILToken`
- `UnsafeValueBuffer`
- `PackIndex`
- `Word`: A machine-sized word
- `IntLiteral`
- `FPIEEE16`: 16-bit floating point number ([IEEE754 half-precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format))
- `FPIEEE32`: underpins [`Float`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/float) ([IEEE754 single-precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format))
- `FPIEEE64`: underpins [`Double`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/double) ([IEEE754 double-precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format))
- `FPIEEE80`: underpins [`Float80`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/float80) ([an x86 extended precision float](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#x86_extended_precision_format))
- `FPIEEE128`: 128-bit floating point number ([IEEE754 quadruple floating point number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format))
- `FPPPC128`: ["PowerPC 2xDouble"](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/1470023addfb86d6cc39e618b7ac48b7dc2b8f6d/include/swift/AST/ASTContext.h#L1019)
- `AnyObject`: underpins [`AnyObject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/AnyObject)

Comment: Incidentally, you get access to the `Builtin` module by passing the [`-parse-stdlib`](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Aapple%2Fswift%20parse-stdlib&type=code) flag to the compiler. That’s why only the standard library has access to `Builtin`.

Answer (score 0):

There are five categories of types in Swift: Class instances, structs, enums, tuples, and closures.

As you noticed, things that are primitives in other languages are often structs in Swift, like Int, Double, String. Optionals are enums.

There is no root type.

Comment: How can there be no root type? Doesn't either the compiler or the programmer need some way to represent an actual pattern of bits in memory? In C, `int x = 5;` would store the bits `000...000101` in memory. When we say `let x = 5` in Swift, we create an `Int` instance, which (since it is a struct) must somehow set the value of a field that somewhere along the line actually changes the values in memory. How is this accomplished if no root type exists?